# removing blockquote from Wordpress post

Tags: php, wordpress

I have the following function which puts just the content on the page (images were removed)

```
    <?php
        $content = preg_replace('/(<img [^>]*>)/', '', get_the_content());
        $content = wpautop($content); // Add paragraph-tags
        $content = str_replace('<p></p>', '', $content); // remove empty paragraphs
        echo $content;
    ?>
```

I want to remove the blockquotes from the content as well but am not sure how to adjust my code

Comment: Use another preg replace for `blockquote` tags?

Comment: dont use regex for processing html. use [DomDocument](http://php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this :

```
   $content = preg_replace('/<blockquote>(.*?)<\/blockquote>/', '', get_the_content());
```

Comment: in the above function you have mentioned before `img`  one.

Comment: it seems to work if put right under the img one so that's good enough for me. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

An alternative route you could take with editing the content markup is using an HTML parser like simplehtmldom:

http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net

Just include the parser in your PHP script and then select $content for parsing:

```
$html = str_get_html($content);
```

Then remove block quotes with this:

```
$block = $html->find("blockquote");
$block->outertext = '';
```

After block quotes are removed just output the final result:

```
echo $html;
```

You can remove any other tags too, by id or class, and also edit tag attributes with this parser. Hope this helps. Wish you the best.